# Reference different raw resource depending on screen orientation

Tags: android

I would like to define raw resources in my dimens.xml file like I define margins, padding for different screen orientations.

I've tried this:

> `<item name="my_res" type="raw" format="string">R.raw.test</item>`

But that doesn't seem to be working.

When I try to fetch id of that resource, it is not correct:

```
    TypedValue out = new TypedValue();

    getResources().getValue(R.raw.my_res, out, true);
    int resId = out.resourceId;
```

Any suggestions how to han

Answer (score 0):

Use `Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` for obtaining ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT and ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE values indicating current orientation. Based on this, get appropiate raw resource.

```
TypedValue out = new TypedValue();
int resId;
if(Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 1) { //1 for Portrait and 2 for Landscape 
    getResources().getValue(R.raw.my_res, out, true);
    resId = out.resourceId;
} else {
    getResources().getValue(R.raw.my_res_alternate, out, true);
    resId = out.resourceId;
}
```

Do any necesary change, but this is the main idea.